# Separate multiple rows at once in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame where two columns contain character strings, and the other two contain vectors. In every row, the vectors all contain the same number of elements, each corresponding with the vector elements in the other vector column - as well as the character string in one of the character columns. See example below:

```
> head(df)
   features.properties.messageType    features.properties.areaDesc features.properties.geocode.SAME features.properties.geocode.UGC
1                           Update Jefferson, MO; St. Francois, MO            c("029099", "029187")           c("MOC099", "MOC187")
2                            Alert        Monroe, IL; Randolph, IL            c("017133", "017157")           c("ILC133", "ILC157")
3                            Alert            Dent, MO; Howell, MO            c("029065", "029091")           c("MOC065", "MOC091")
4                           Update             Texas; Dent; Howell  c("029215", "029065", "029091") c("MOZ082", "MOZ083", "MOZ097")
5                           Update         Clay, AR; Craighead, AR            c("005021", "005031")           c("ARC021", "ARC031")
6                           Update       Crittenden, AR; Cross, AR            c("005035", "005037")           c("ARC035", "ARC037")
```

So, in this example, in the first row, Jefferson, MO corresponds with "029099" and "MOC099". How could I separate each character string and vector element into individual rows, such that the first elements all share one row, the second elements all share the next row, etc.?

---

### Dput

```
#turn on packages
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(plotly)

#access API & create data.frame
active_alerts <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(content(GET(url = "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active?area=MO"),
                                                "text", encoding = "UTF-8"), flatten = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(c("features.properties.messageType","features.properties.areaDesc","features.properties.geocode.SAME","features.properties.geocode.UGC"))

> active_alerts
  features.properties.messageType
1                          Update
2                          Update
3                           Alert
4                           Alert
5                           Alert
6                          Update
7                          Update
8                          Update
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     features.properties.areaDesc
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Howell, MO; Oregon, MO; Ozark, MO; Shannon, MO
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Bond, IL; Clinton, IL; Fayette, IL; Madison, IL; Marion, IL; Monroe, IL; Randolph, IL; St. Clair, IL; Washington, IL; Iron, MO; Jefferson, MO; Madison, MO; Reynolds, MO; Ste. Genevieve, MO; St. Francois, MO; Washington, MO
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Clay, AR; Craighead, AR; Greene, AR; Poinsett, AR; Dunklin, MO
4                                                                                                                                                                             Crittenden, AR; Cross, AR; Lee, AR; Mississippi, AR; Phillips, AR; St. Francis, AR; Pemiscot, MO; Coahoma, MS; DeSoto, MS; Marshall, MS; Panola, MS; Quitman, MS; Tate, MS; Tunica, MS; Carroll, TN; Crockett, TN; Dyer, TN; Fayette, TN; Gibson, TN; Haywood, TN; Henry, TN; Lake, TN; Lauderdale, TN; Madison, TN; Obion, TN; Shelby, TN; Tipton, TN; Weakley, TN
5                                                                                                                                                                                                        Alexander, IL; Franklin, IL; Hamilton, IL; Jackson, IL; Jefferson, IL; Johnson, IL; Perry, IL; Pope, IL; Pulaski, IL; Saline, IL; Union, IL; Wayne, IL; White, IL; Williamson, IL; Bollinger, MO; Butler, MO; Cape Girardeau, MO; Carter, MO; Mississippi, MO; New Madrid, MO; Perry, MO; Ripley, MO; Scott, MO; Stoddard, MO; Wayne, MO
6 Jefferson; Wayne; Edwards; Wabash; Perry; Franklin; Hamilton; White; Jackson; Williamson; Saline; Gallatin; Union; Johnson; Pope; Hardin; Alexander; Pulaski; Massac; Gibson; Pike; Posey; Vanderburgh; Warrick; Spencer; Fulton; Hickman; Carlisle; Ballard; McCracken; Graves; Livingston; Marshall; Calloway; Crittenden; Lyon; Trigg; Caldwell; Union; Webster; Hopkins; Christian; Henderson; Daviess; McLean; Muhlenberg; Todd; Perry; Bollinger; Cape Girardeau; Wayne; Carter; Ripley; Butler; Stoddard; Scott; Mississippi; New Madrid
7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Clay; Greene; Craighead; Poinsett; Mississippi; Cross; Crittenden; St. Francis; Lee; Phillips; Dunklin; Pemiscot; DeSoto; Tunica; Tate; Coahoma; Quitman; Lake; Obion; Weakley; Henry; Dyer; Gibson; Carroll; Lauderdale; Tipton; Haywood; Crockett; Madison; Shelby; Fayette
8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Mississippi, AR; Pemiscot, MO; Dyer, TN; Lake, TN; Lauderdale, TN
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                features.properties.geocode.SAME
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 029091, 029149, 029153, 029203
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 017005, 017027, 017051, 017119, 017121, 017133, 017157, 017163, 017189, 029093, 029099, 029123, 029179, 029186, 029187, 029221
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         005021, 005031, 005055, 005111, 029069
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 005035, 005037, 005077, 005093, 005107, 005123, 029155, 028027, 028033, 028093, 028107, 028119, 028137, 028143, 047017, 047033, 047045, 047047, 047053, 047075, 047079, 047095, 047097, 047113, 047131, 047157, 047167, 047183
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         017003, 017055, 017065, 017077, 017081, 017087, 017145, 017151, 017153, 017165, 017181, 017191, 017193, 017199, 029017, 029023, 029031, 029035, 029133, 029143, 029157, 029181, 029201, 029207, 029223
6 017081, 017191, 017047, 017185, 017145, 017055, 017065, 017193, 017077, 017199, 017165, 017059, 017181, 017087, 017151, 017069, 017003, 017153, 017127, 018051, 018125, 018129, 018163, 018173, 018147, 021075, 021105, 021039, 021007, 021145, 021083, 021139, 021157, 021035, 021055, 021143, 021221, 021033, 021225, 021233, 021107, 021047, 021101, 021059, 021149, 021177, 021219, 029157, 029017, 029031, 029223, 029035, 029181, 029023, 029207, 029201, 029133, 029143
7                                                                                                                                                                                                                         005021, 005055, 005031, 005111, 005093, 005037, 005035, 005123, 005077, 005107, 029069, 029155, 028033, 028143, 028137, 028027, 028119, 047095, 047131, 047183, 047079, 047045, 047053, 047017, 047097, 047167, 047075, 047033, 047113, 047157, 047047
8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         005093, 029155, 047045, 047095, 047097
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 features.properties.geocode.UGC
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 MOC091, MOC149, MOC153, MOC203
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ILC005, ILC027, ILC051, ILC119, ILC121, ILC133, ILC157, ILC163, ILC189, MOC093, MOC099, MOC123, MOC179, MOC186, MOC187, MOC221
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ARC021, ARC031, ARC055, ARC111, MOC069
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ARC035, ARC037, ARC077, ARC093, ARC107, ARC123, MOC155, MSC027, MSC033, MSC093, MSC107, MSC119, MSC137, MSC143, TNC017, TNC033, TNC045, TNC047, TNC053, TNC075, TNC079, TNC095, TNC097, TNC113, TNC131, TNC157, TNC167, TNC183
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ILC003, ILC055, ILC065, ILC077, ILC081, ILC087, ILC145, ILC151, ILC153, ILC165, ILC181, ILC191, ILC193, ILC199, MOC017, MOC023, MOC031, MOC035, MOC133, MOC143, MOC157, MOC181, MOC201, MOC207, MOC223
6 ILZ075, ILZ076, ILZ077, ILZ078, ILZ080, ILZ081, ILZ082, ILZ083, ILZ084, ILZ085, ILZ086, ILZ087, ILZ088, ILZ089, ILZ090, ILZ091, ILZ092, ILZ093, ILZ094, INZ081, INZ082, INZ085, INZ086, INZ087, INZ088, KYZ001, KYZ002, KYZ003, KYZ004, KYZ005, KYZ006, KYZ007, KYZ008, KYZ009, KYZ010, KYZ011, KYZ012, KYZ013, KYZ014, KYZ015, KYZ016, KYZ017, KYZ018, KYZ019, KYZ020, KYZ021, KYZ022, MOZ076, MOZ086, MOZ087, MOZ100, MOZ107, MOZ108, MOZ109, MOZ110, MOZ111, MOZ112, MOZ114
7                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ARZ009, ARZ018, ARZ026, ARZ027, ARZ028, ARZ035, ARZ036, ARZ048, ARZ049, ARZ058, MOZ113, MOZ115, MSZ001, MSZ007, MSZ008, MSZ010, MSZ011, TNZ001, TNZ002, TNZ003, TNZ004, TNZ019, TNZ020, TNZ021, TNZ048, TNZ049, TNZ050, TNZ051, TNZ052, TNZ088, TNZ089
8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ARC093, MOC155, TNC045, TNC095, TNC097
```

Comment: Could you share your sample data with `dput()` so it is easy to import and test solutions and so the column classes are clear?

Comment: Provided `dput()`!

Comment: Updated again with output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may create a `list` column for `features.properties.areaDesc` by splitting at the `;` and then `unnest` all the `list` columns

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(features.properties.areaDesc = 
         strsplit(features.properties.areaDesc, ";\\s*")) %>%
   unnest(where(is.list))
```

Comment: A couple tweaks:
- Separator should be ";\\s*"
 - Column name in `strsplit` needs a 'c' at the end

Thank you!

Comment: @SourceCoda sorry I meant `;`, but somehow in the code had a typo (as I couldn't test it)